# Unable to deploy maven to Github

Tags: maven, github

I'm having a bit of an issue when trying to do `mvn deploy`

The error I see is:

```
Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil.
```

For the github site plugin.

This is the complete log:

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil.
[ERROR] Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil. (422)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.9:site (default) on project abc: Error creating commit: Invalid request.

Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil.
Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil. (422)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating commit: Invalid request.

Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil.
Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil. (422)
        at com.github.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:440)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.RequestException: Invalid request.

Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil.
Expected data to be of type "object"; value was: nil. (422)
        at org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.GitHubClient.createException(GitHubClient.java:552)
        at org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.GitHubClient.sendJson(GitHubClient.java:643)
        at org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.GitHubClient.post(GitHubClient.java:757)
        at org.eclipse.egit.github.core.service.DataService.createCommit(DataService.java:397)
        at com.github.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:434)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: You should use `mvn site-deploy` instead cause site-maven-plugin is intended to work for the site.

Comment: https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/69 has a discussion on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occures because of the recent API changes. Use Version 0.10-SNAPSHOT until the final release is out.

More details and a fix is [described](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/69) in github issues.

**Update**:
The release 0.10 is out, and the described error is fixed for most users. 
Check the [issue](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/69) to find out more.

Comment: [ERROR] Plugin com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.10-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:jar:0.10-SNAPSHOT

Comment: well you should check out the code and build it yourself or add add the sonatype snapshot repositories to your pom.

Comment: I don't see any 0.10-SNAPSHOT on https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/github/github/site-maven-plugin/

Comment: you are right.Don't know where it came from in my case. Anyway building it yourself will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2014-09-24 Problem goes away when the github profile is changed and has a public e-mail address and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
  <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

is used. See discussion as https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/69

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this appears to be a github api issue.  The plugin worked fine the last time I used it and now it doesn't.  Upgrading from 0.8 to 0.9 made no difference.